# What does uglifyjs gain by moving expressions to the `if` condition clause?

Tags: javascript, optimization, uglifyjs

The following code

```
console.log("foo");

if (window.x !== window.y) {
    const x = "x";
    console.log(x);
}
```

is minified using uglifyjs to

```
if(console.log("foo"),window.x!==window.y){const x="x";console.log(x)}
```

As one can see it's not longer than the more straightforward

```
console.log("foo");if(window.x!==window.y){const x="x";console.log(x)}
```

So what do they gain by moving it? Is it some tricky engine-specific optimisation or there is a reason that I cannot see?

Comment: With the right options uglifyjs also *optimizes* `Function()` into `function(){}`, apparently because that's shorter when gzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else pointed me to a place in their readme where they clarify it

> consecutive statements in blocks are merged into a sequence; in many cases, this leaves blocks with a single statement, so then we can remove the block brackets.

So it is not the case here, but it saves 2 characters when you have something like

```
if (<expr>) {
    console.log("foo");

    if (window.x !== window.y) {
        const x = "x";
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @GOTO, the second variant may be the same length, it is longer when gzipped:

```
$ echo 'if(console.log("foo"),window.x!==window.y){const x="x";console.log(x)}' | gzip | wc --bytes
74
$ echo 'console.log("foo");if(window.x!==window.y){const x="x";console.log(x)}' | gzip | wc --bytes
76
```

Comment: See the "real answer" below :-) (+1'd anyway though)